# Passing a character string to a function parameter in C

Tags: c, string, function, parameter-passing

Bear with me as I am relatively new to C.

I am trying to create a function, which could take the names of musical notes (i.e. D or D#) as an argument, and return the value of their corresponding midi note number ([midi number table](http://support.keithmcmillen.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200973519/midi_note_reference.png)) with a second argument for octave.

However, I seem to be having problems with either the initialisation of the string, or using it within the function. This is the function I wrote:

```
int midi_number(char note[], int octave)
{
    int midiNumber

    if (note[1] = '#')
    {
        switch(note[0])
        {
        case 'C': case 'c':
        midiNumber = 25;
        break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
        midiNumber = 27;
        break;
        ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(note[0])
        {
        case 'C': case 'c':
        midiNumber = 24;
        break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
        midiNumber = 26;
        break;
        ...
        }
    }
    return (midiNumber + (octave * 12))
}
```

I am then calling the function as follows:

```
midi_number('C#', 1);
```

Hopefully this gets across the idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I have researched into pointers and arrays, but I can't see how it applies to what I am doing.

Any help massively appreciated!

Comment: You use single quotes `'` for *character* literals, and double quotes `"` for string literals.

Comment: This won't even compile. Mismatched types, missing semicolon, etc.

Comment: Also, think about the difference between comparison and assignment operators.

Comment: Both of my above points should have been explained by almost any good beginners book. Maybe you should throw out the one you have and [find another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`note[1] = '#'` is *assigning* `'#'` to `note[1]`, not comparing them.

You need `note[1] == '#'` inside your if statement.

Comment: Thanks! very stupid mistake. That,  plus cleaning up the syntax problems has got it working.